# How to completely remove VS 2013 and SQL Server Data Tool

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssdt-bi

I have an evaluation copy of VS 2013 and a registered version of SQL 2014 Dev installed on my PC. I created some SSIS in VS 2013. Yesterday, VS said my trial version is over and it won't open my SSIS package anymore. So I removed VS 2013 and everyting related 2013 from my PC (there is still VS 2005/2008/2010 installed, with SQL 2005/2008 R2/2014). I also removed SQL Server Data Tools (which come with VS 2013).

Now, I want to reinstall SSDT, so I downloaded the package (SSDTBI_x86_ENU.exe) but it says it's already installed.

In the SQL installer, I see SSDT installed as a shared component, but I have removed it from my PC. So now, I'm stuck, I can't open my SSIS package anymore!

I tried to download a new trial for VS 2013, but of course, it won't work, saying the trial is already expired.

How can I fix this?? I need to open those SSIS packages.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully used MicrosoftFixit.ProgramInstallUninstall.RNP.Run.exe from Microsoft to uninstall stubborn programs, especially Microsofts' own ones, usually when they cant find installation sources to run the uninstaller. It says it doesn't work on Windows 10 (if you are running that) but I have used it on Windows 10. Here is the link
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/mats/program_install_and_uninstall

It has a couple of drawbacks. You can only uninstall programs one at a time. I use it by running the program, accepting the license conditions, Selecting "Detect problems and let me apply the fixes", then choosing "Uninstalling", and then selecting the program I am having trouble with. The list you get is more comprehensive than the one found in appwiz.cpl